# selecting specfic option from a drop down menu using js

Tags: javascript, html

HTML code :

```
<select id = "menu">
<option value="2017">2017</option>
<option value="2016">2016</option>
<option value="2015">2015</option>
</select>
```

What I have tried :

```
document.getElementById("menu").selectedIndex = 2015;
```

Comment: using jquery `$("#meno).val(2015)`

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("menu").value =  2015;
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByid is not a function

Comment: Programming is case sensitive. Try again.